# Elements with visible text labels do not have matching accessible names

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, cart

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6hlO.png)
How to solve this issue?

I want to know how to solve the issue of 'Elements with visible text labels do not have matching accessible names.' on my add to cart button. I cannot find how to do that.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the `aria-label` attribute on the `a` tag to a **substring** of the text content within normally solves this problem. In your case, it could be "Add to cart" or "Add to cart - productname", but "Add productname to cart" would not do.